# Is it possible: Select a values form datatable based on string comparison?

Tags: string, vb.net, select, datatable

I would like to filter datatable based on the given thresholds. These thresholds are strings but the value is 'numeric'. and select on datatable convert it as they are integers.

The thresholds are defined as follows:

```
custFrom = "1070000"
custTo = "69020"
```

I have a datatable with codes so I have tried the select query on the dt as I would like to filter the values in the given range.

```
CodeList.select("[CCode]  >= "+ custFrom + " AND [CCode] <="+ custTo + " ").CopyToDataTable
```

What select is doing is to give me the range like the values as a numbers not as a string. What I mean:
The value 602 should be included in the range but it is not:

> "602" > "1070000" and "602" < "69020" --> TRUE

Is there any way to use select on datatable (CodeList) but using the vb.net feature like string comparison and not convert the values to integers?

Comment: I would try with a custom column of type string calculated with an expression and then filter on that column

Comment: You should go away from concatenating your strings. Right now, it will be considered as a number.

Comment: Can some explain how you can compare "number as string" > "number as string" ?? That's how i understand this question!

Comment: I know it is considered as a number but this is not what I am looking for. I need it to be considered as a STRING. That is why I am looking for help.

Comment: @siggi_pop. Find the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/comparison-operators

Comment: @donchuan Well then you need to Cast / Convert! how else would you get a different type?

Comment: @donchuan that link you sent, shows how to compare numbers, **not** string!

Comment: @siggi_pop. All used values are Strings but vb.net convert it to numbers. I would like to know how to stop vb.net converting the values.

Comment: It should treat the strings as strings if you put double-quotes around them: `CodeList.select("[CCode]  >= """ & custFrom & """ AND [CCode] <= """ & custTo & + """).CopyToDataTable`.

Comment: I have found the solution. It is really close to what @AndrewMorton suggested the point is to use single quotes not the double ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the only issue was not to use double quotes but the sigle ones.

Here is the query which actually works:

```
CodeList.select("[CCode] >= '" & custFrom & "' AND [CCode] <= '" & custTo & + "'").CopyToDataTable
```

Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer: 
It seems you need to do alphabetical comparison, instead of numerical comparison.
So basically your logic says: "1070000" is considered a **lower** value than "69020".
So consider that you have one column table with 4 rows {"106","601","602","70000"} and

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("CCode")
dt.Rows.Add("106")
dt.Rows.Add("601")
dt.Rows.Add("602")
dt.Rows.Add("70000")
```

you need select rows 2 and 3 ("601", "602"), then this is query statment you use

```
Dim rows As DataRow() = dt.Select("[CCode]  >= " + custFrom + " AND [CCode] <= " + custTo)
```

then you should treat you upper and lower bounds as string when comparing (single qoutes inside double qoutes)  "'number'"

```
Dim custFrom As String = "'1070000'"
Dim custTo As String = "'69020'"
```

`rows` array now contains 2 rows with values { "601", "602"} 
And that's it. The Select method implicitly filters in alphabetical order.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution in explanation what was the point in string comparision.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please consider closing the thread as answered, thank you :)